# Parent route loader loads for every child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using nested routes in React-Router and when I redirect to a child route using `redirect`, the parent loader loads first. I want to ignore the parent loader when I redirect. Is this possible?

I've tried to add loader for the child route, but nevertheless the parent loader loads first on redirect.

Code looks like this:

```
path: ':gameId',
id: 'game-details',
loader: gameDetailsLoader,
children: [
  {
    index: true,
    element: <GameDetailsPage />,
    action: gameDetailsAction
  },
  {
    path: 'completion',
    element: <CompleteEventPage />,
    action: completeAction
  },
  {
    path: 'postDelete',
    element: <PostDeletePage />,
    loader: privateRouteloader
  }
]
```

When I use `redirect` to redirect to `"postDelete"` path, the `gameDetailsLoader` loads first and I want to skip this.

In the GameDetailsPage I have the loader: "gameDetailsLoader" and action: "gameDetailsAction". I`m redirecting from the "gameDetailsAction" to postDelete path. The action deletes some content and here I face the issue. When I`m redirected to the postDelete page, React router loads the "gameDetailsLoader" as parent loader first. As I`ve deleted some content I`m no longer able to get this data from the server and therefore receive an error. I was just wondering if there is a way to skip parent loader, but couldn`t find this in the documentation. I`ve solved the issue by creating another path for the postDelete element, however nested routes seems to be the logical approach in this scenario.

Comment: So what route path do you want the `gameDetailsLoader` loader to be called? Where are you using `redirect`? Please [edit] to clarify and to provide a more complete [mcve].

Comment: gameDetailsLoader is loaded for every nested route and that`s what I want to adjust if possible. Question was edited with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gameDetailsLoader` is called on any `"/:gameId/*"` route.

If you want the `gameDetailsLoader` loader function to be called ***only on*** the `"/:gameId"` path then move it to the specific route.

```
path: ':gameId',
id: 'game-details',
children: [
  {
    index: true,
    element: <GameDetailsPage />,
    loader: gameDetailsLoader, // <--
    action: gameDetailsAction
  },
  {
    path: 'completion',
    element: <CompleteEventPage />,
    action: completeAction
  },
  {
    path: 'postDelete',
    element: <PostDeletePage />,
    loader: privateRouteloader
  }
]
```